# Where can you read about the future of Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

As many already know the Unity Desktop Environment (DE) will no longer be actively developed by Canonical (the makers of Ubuntu). Instead they will be shuffling some resources into "tweaking" Gnome DE.

I would like to read up on the progress of Ubuntu developments and wonder what sites can be followed. I've already heard about "OMG Ubuntu" and have read some of their articles.

Comment: Was Unity ever, in a strict sense, a Desktop Environment?

Comment: It was a pretty face on Gnome gsettings, dsettings and whatnotsettings I guess. Bundled with Eye of Gnome, Gnome Nautilus and other apps.

Comment: It all starts here: http://www.markshuttleworth.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't think of a general official "news" site for ubuntu besides the general linux sites or computer news sites etc.

But if you actually want to see what happens exactly in which release you could follow their milestones on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu